# Java: recursion within main-class calls subclass-method instead of its own method

Tags: java, recursion, subclass, mainclass

Example:

```
class MainClass {
    public doIt() {
        ...
        else doIt();
    }
}

class SubClass extends MainClass {
    @Override
    public doIt() {
        super.doIt();
        ...
    }
}
```

Now the problem is:

- I call SubClass.doIt()
- MainClass.doIt() is called
- MainClass.doIt() makes recursion calling doIt()
  But: the SubClass.doIt() is called instead of MainClass.doIt()

That is very strange behaviour and problems are programmed! I tried to call the recursion with this.doIt() but that didn't help.
Someone has an idea?

Thanks alot for your answers, this problem is solved.

Comment: That's polymorphism for you.

Comment: "*That is very strange behaviour*" not really, `else doIt()` is same as `else this.doIt()` but `this` refers to current instance, and thanks to dynamic-binding (polymorphism mechanism) code from method of class closest to current type of `this` is called. Since closest class to `SubClass` containing `doIt` is `SubClass` itself this code is invoked.

Comment: That's the supposed behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the supposed behavior, by not setting a method `final`, that means it can be `override`n, so you must always take into account someone can do this. Call's to that method **are never guaranteed** to be to the method at that level.

You can however solve this problem elegantly, by using a (`protected`) `final` method:

```
class MainClass {

    protected final void innerDoIt () { //final: so no @Override
        ...
        else innerDoIt();
    }

    public void doIt() {
        innerDoIt();
    }

}
```

And then:

```
class SubClass extends MainClass {

    @Override
    public doIt() {
        super.doIt();
        ...
    }
}
```

`final` ensures, the method can't be overriden. So at that moment, you have a contract (guarantee) that the `innerDoIt` method is indeed the `innerDoIt` method you think it is.

So in case **you don't wan't the caller to get overriden**, simply hedge it into another `final` method. By making it `protected`, that method can also be called by the `SubClass`.

Comment: ok didn't know that, a miracle that all my stuff runs up to now :p - thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.doIt();
        System.out.println();
        A a = new B();
        a.doIt();
    }


    public static class A{
        boolean check=false;
        public void doIt(){
            System.out.println("A start");
            if(check){

            }
            else{
                check = true;
                doIt();
            }
            System.out.println("A end");
        }
    }
    public static class B extends A{
        @Override
        public void doIt() {
            System.out.println("B start");
            super.doIt();
            System.out.println("B end");
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, both `b` and `a` are instances of class `B`, so as you probably expect, a.doIt() and b.doIt() will output the same result.

```
B start
A start
B start
A start
A end
B end
A end
B end

B start
A start
B start
A start
A end
B end
A end
B end
```

When you call `doIt()`, you are implicitly calling `this.doIt()`, and `this` is an instance of class `B`. There is no syntax to do what you want do without seperating the content of `doIt()` (see CommuSoft's answer)